# Use Oracle INSTR function to search for multiple strings

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, string

In Oracle/PLSQL, the `instr` function returns the location of a sub-string in a string.

If the sub-string is not found, then `instr` will return `0`.

I want to search multiple sub-strings in a string and return the first non-zero value. This can be achieved using `regexp_instr`, but I'd like a non-`regexp_` solution.

**Example:**

```
regexp_instr('500 Oracle Parkway, Redwood Shores, CA','(Apple|Park|Shores)')
```

should return 12 (the location of 'Park').

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[INSTR](http://techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/instr.php) doesn't support regex ORs - you'd have to define INSTR function calls for each substring you want to check for.  The equivalent of `regexp_instr('500 Oracle Parkway, Redwood Shores, CA','(Apple|Park|Shores)')` would be:

```
WHERE (INSTR('500 Oracle Parkway, Redwood Shores, CA', 'Apple') > 0
      OR
      INSTR('500 Oracle Parkway, Redwood Shores, CA', 'Park') > 0
      OR
      INSTR('500 Oracle Parkway, Redwood Shores, CA', 'Shores') > 0)
```

Depending on your needs, full text search functionality might be more towards what you want?

Answer (score 2):

Obviously without regexp there won't be such an elegant solution, unless you write your own PL/SQL function that does the same job. Otherwise you would have to do something like this:

```
with data as (select '500 Oracle Parkway, Redwood Shores, CA' string from dual)
select nvl(min(pos),0) from
( select instr(data.string, 'Apple') pos
  union all
  select instr(data.string, 'Park') pos
  union all
  select instr(data.string, 'Shores') pos
)
where pos > 0;
```

Comment: I found this to be an amazing answer!  So I tried it.  And I took a look at the performance of it.  It sends the query to Oracle from the PL/SQL interpreter - In other words this is a very slow way to do what you are trying to do!

Comment: @Schlump: "sends the query to Oracle from the PL/SQL interpreter"?

Comment: Yes I wondered quite what that meant too, but let it pass.  SQL from PL/SQL I suppose.

Comment: It has to pass it to the PL/SQL engine, because this is not an operation that can trivially be performed using indexes or simple sub strings. If performance is vital, write  package with a deterministic function, returning the first non-0 position, that can then be used in a computed index.

Answer (score 0):

please check with below---

```
select regexp_instr ('500 Oracle Parkway, Redwood Shores, CA', 'Apple|Park|Shores', 1, 1, 0, 'i') as result
from dual;
```

Comment: The OP explicitly asked for a solution without regexes.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    coalesce(
        nullif(instr('500 Oracle Parkway, Redwood Shores, CA','Apple'),0),
        nullif(instr('500 Oracle Parkway, Redwood Shores, CA','Park'),0),
        nullif(instr('500 Oracle Parkway, Redwood Shores, CA','Shores'),0)
    ) as xxx
from dual
```

Answer (score 0):

according to me **instr** will not give every position of the character in the string,so use the below code if you need.

```
 SELECT literal,indx FROM  (SELECT substr('HelloWorld',level,1) as literal,level as indx FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= length('HelloWorld'))WHERE literal IN ('l','o') ORDER BY literal
```

in the above i was checking the literal 'l' in the string 'HelloWorld',the above query gives all the matched positions.you can enhance the above code to a fucntion and use according to requirements.